# Implement Android picture viewer

Tags: android

i just wanted to write a picture viewer for my android app. I saw that the gallery view is deprecated. So i really dont want to use it for new code. I already searched for a replacement but only found "care for yourself" answers. So what's the best way to implement it? ViewPager? Horizontalscrollview?

I want to swipe the images (fling is not neccessary) and at the top i want a small preview row with thumbnails of the whole picture album (up to 10 pictures). I want the thumbnail row to be "flingable". If i click a picture there it should open at the bigger view below.

Are there any tutorials/open source apps where i can see some code how they did it?

Greets

Comment: http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/BitmapFun.zip